# Selecting a single HighCharts container causes other containers to change position

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am using HighCharts, and I am seeing some weird functionality when selecting one of the charts.

If and only if I select the top right gauge, it causes other gauges to move their position. All other gauges work fine.

I am having trouble figuring out why this is happening, and was hoping someone could point out what I am missing.

My back end uses Python Flask module, HTML uses JINJA2 Framework, and JavaScript.

### Front.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{url_for('static',filename='style.css')}}"/>
</head>


<body id="body"
<div class="header">
        <span id="headerText">Current ISIS Connections </span>
    </div>



<div id="gaugeTable">

        <div id="Workgroup-01" class="gaugeCell"> </div>
        <div id="Workgroup-02" class="gaugeCell" ></div>
        <div id="Workgroup-04" class="gaugeCell"></div>
        <div id="Workgroup-05" class="gaugeCell"></div>

        <div id="Workgroup-06" class="gaugeCell"></div>
        <div id="Workgroup-03" class="gaugeCell"></div>
        <div id="Workgroup-3A" class="gaugeCell"></div>
        <div id="Workgroup-07" class="gaugeCell"> </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var workgroups =['Workgroup-01','Workgroup-02','Workgroup-03','Workgroup-3A','Workgroup-04',
        'Workgroup-05','Workgroup-06','Workgroup-07'];

$(function ()
 {

    var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: 'test',

        pane: {
            // Positioning
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            // img size
            size: '100%',
            // full circle/half circle
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            // gauge coloring
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#000',
                // Inner semi circle sizing
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                // Set the limits for coloring
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            // Outside Line buffer
            lineWidth: 0,

            // IDK
            minorTickInterval: null,
            // IDK
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            //IDK
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                // Title Location
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                // Bottom Label Offset
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 15,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };


    // The  gauges
    //
    //
    //
    for( i in workgroups){


        $('#'+workgroups[i]).highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
             min: 0,
             max: 200,
                title: {
                    text: workgroups[i]
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: workgroups[i],
                data: [0],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">clients</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' clients'
                }
            }]

        }));
    }
 }
);



function get_gauge_data(){
   $.get('get_gauge_data',
        function(returnedData){


                $.each(returnedData, function(key,value){
                    for(i in workgroups){


                        divID = "#"+workgroups[i];

                         var chart = $(divID).highcharts(),
                            point,
                            newVal,
                            inc;

                         if (chart) {
                            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                            newVal = value[workgroups[i]];
                         }
                         point.update(newVal);
                    }



                });

        }
   );


}



$(document).ready(function() {
    //trigger repeating calls
    get_gauge_data();
    setInterval(get_gauge_data, 5000);
});

var highCharts = document.getElementsByClassName("gaugeCell");

var highChartsListener = function(){

        for(var i = 0;i<highCharts.length;i++){
             if(this == highCharts[i]){
                $(this).addClass("selected");
             }else{
                $(highCharts[i]).removeClass("selected");

             }
        }
}

for(var i = 0;i<highCharts.length;i++){
    highCharts[i].addEventListener('click', highChartsListener,false);
}






</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Styles.css

```css
/* reset browser defaults */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em,
img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i,
center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table,
caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details,
embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby,
section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}




/* **************************************************************************************** */
/* Main body formatting */
body {
    background-color:#D7D5C9;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-align: left;
}



/* **************************************************************************************** */
/* Header and Footer */
.header {
    background-color: #4C453D;
    color:#FF6C00;
    font-size:24px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    padding:8px 25px 50px;
}

/*
.footer{
    background-color: #4C453D;
    color:#FF6C00;
    text-indent: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:12px;
}
/* manually set width of the 1st/status column so it's big enough and fixed */
.footer #status {
    width:70px;
}

*/




/* **************************************************************************************** */
/* Gauge Formatting */

.test{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margine: 5px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 900px;
}

#gaugeTable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 900px;
}


.gaugeCell{
    border-width:4px;
    border-color:gray;
    border-style:solid;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}

.selected {
    border: 3px solid #0E5342;
    background-color: #A8DB92;

}
```

### distorted img

[image: Normally the Highlighted Part has the gauges]

Comment: Is all of that HTML and CSS necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I had tried to trim it, but as the issue may ahve been in the creation of the Gauges itself, I decided to supply more info than elss

Comment: For future questions, if you just have HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, you can embed your code in a runnable "Stack Snippet" by clicking the document icon with the `< >` image in the WYSIWYG editor. That will make it easier for us to see the issue in real-time, instead of you having to take a screenshot :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tyler, I will make note for future WebDev questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a couple options.

- Instead of floats, use `display: inline-block` and remove `white-space: nowrap` from the parent. This will fit them all in the parent div.
- The added green border is 3x, while the normal border is 4px. Changing it to also to 4px keeps all the dimensions the same and retains layout.
- Using "[clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)" on the last item in the row will reset their height to fit.

Comment: Thanks PFM! I updated with regards to your second comment, and it is working.  However, I do not understand why the image would resize if Selected Border is less than the actual border, the intent was that 75% of the border should be colored, maintaining the original 100% size

Comment: @Busturdust It is basically because of the way floats work with the box model in CSS. [This](http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/) is a good article on it.